# Strange difference of disk size

Tags: centos, disk-usage, google-cloud, lsblk

I have a Google Cloud Instance:

When i check the disk space with two different command it show:

df -H

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
/dev/sda2        11G  3.1G  7.5G  30% /  
devtmpfs        300M     0  300M   0% /dev  
tmpfs           308M     0  308M   0% /dev/shm  
tmpfs           308M   34M  274M  12% /run  
tmpfs           308M     0  308M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup  
/dev/sda1       210M   12M  198M   6% /boot/efi  
tmpfs            62M     0   62M   0% /run/user/1001
```

lsblk

```
 NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT  
 sda      8:0    0   30G  0 disk  
 ├─sda1   8:1    0  200M  0 part /boot/efi  
 └─sda2   8:2    0 29.8G  0 part /
```

Why i have these difference?

I want that my disk have all the **30G** of space and not **11G**.

Comment: Maybe the file system is not filling the whole partition. How did you create/modify the partition and file system?

Comment: Assuming this is an ext* partition you can resize the disk with `resize2fs /dev/sda2`

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Comment: When i do `resize2fs /dev/sda2` i receive:

`resize2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda2
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.`

Comment: Please don't do that online.

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 What do you mean by online?

Comment: With filesystem mounted. But it doesn't seem to be the filesystem smaller than partition problem. Did you just re-write your partition table completely not using a proper partitioning tool?

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克i don't know, can you say to me how to check?